# suppose $a_n>1$ $a_n$is non-decreasing and bounded. prove: $\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}})\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

suppose $a_n>1$, $\{a_n\}$ is non-decreasing and bounded.

prove:

$\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}$ converges

I don't have any idea about how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Note
$$\left(1-\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{a_{n+1}\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}\le\int_{a_{n}}^{a_{n+1}}\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Write
$$\sum \left(1 - \frac{a_n}{a_{n + 1}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n + 1}}}= \sum(a_{n + 1} - a_n)\frac{1}{a_{n + 1}^{3/2}}.$$
Then try to use the Abel's test.

Comment: How to prove $a_{n+1}-a_n$is monotone and bounded?

Comment: You need to show the series $\sum(a_{n + 1} - a_n)$ is convergent. Take a look at the partial sum.

Comment: First note that the sequence $\left\lbrace{a_{n}} \right\rbrace$ converges since it is non-decreasing and bounded:
$\exists \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=a.$
Thus the sequence of partial sums converges too:
$$S_N=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}(a_{n + 1} - a_n)=a_2-a_1+a_3-a_2+\ldots+a_N-a_{N-1}=a_{N}-a_1\underset{n\to\infty}{\to}a-a_1$$
 The second point is that the sequence $\left\lbrace\frac{1}{a_{n + 1}^{3/2}} \right\rbrace$ is monotone and bounded, so we can apply the Abel's test.